Team toolkit chatbot with azure open AI and Bot framework emulator bypass Azure Open AI
I have created a sample project using Teams toolkit to create an assistant in Teams that can avail Azure open AI service (with gpt-4o model). The default code is working fine that is I can run the emulator and send and receive messages via bot framework emulator and it is processing all messages using gpt-4o. However, I want to update the flow and I want to include functionality that for some particular messages the Azure Open AI gpt-4o is not called and a direct response is sent back to user. For any other message, Azure open AI gpt-4o should process the message and send reply back to user.
There are two python files, app.py and bot.py. I tried handling what happens based on input messages in app.py. However, I am not being able to skip Azure open AI in certain scenario without disturbing whole flow.
app.py
"""
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
Licensed under the MIT License.
"""
from http import HTTPStatus

from aiohttp import web
from botbuilder.core.integration import aiohttp_error_middleware
from botbuilder.schema import ChannelAccount

from bot import bot_app
import pandas as pd
from io import BytesIO
import json

from aiohttp import web, ClientRequest
import spacy
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity
import numpy as np
from rapidfuzz import fuzz, process
import re
from botbuilder.schema import Activity
import logging

routes = web.RouteTableDef()

@routes.post("/api/messages")
async def on_messages(req: web.Request) -> web.Response:
    print("on_messages ************* ")
    res = await bot_app.process(req)
        
    if res is not None:
        # Return the response from the bot app processing
        return res
    return web.Response(status=HTTPStatus.OK)


# Load the spaCy model with GloVe vectors
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_md")

#added below function to handle when a particular message comes, change the prompt to be sent to Azure Open AI for processing - this is working fine
async def modify_request_middleware(app, handler):
    async def middleware_handler(req):
        print(f"Next handler: {handler.__name__} of type {type(handler)}")
        print("Middleware triggered")
        if req.path == "/api/messages" and req.method == "POST":
            print("Processing POST request to /api/messages")
            data = await req.json()
            user_input = data.get('text', "").lower()

            print("User Input:", user_input)
            if "hey" in user_input:
                 data['text'] = "Hey, give me recipe of cake which is extremely moist without eggs"
        # Create a new payload with the modified data
        new_payload = json.dumps(data).encode('utf-8')
        req._read_bytes = new_payload
        return await handler(req)
    return middleware_handler


app = web.Application(middlewares=[modify_request_middleware])
app.add_routes(routes)

from config import Config

if __name__ == "__main__":
    web.run_app(app, host="localhost", port=Config.PORT)

Below is code for bot.py
import os
import sys
import traceback

from botbuilder.core import MemoryStorage, TurnContext
from teams import Application, ApplicationOptions, TeamsAdapter
from teams.ai import AIOptions
from teams.ai.models import AzureOpenAIModelOptions, OpenAIModel, OpenAIModelOptions
from teams.ai.planners import ActionPlanner, ActionPlannerOptions
from teams.ai.prompts import PromptManager, PromptManagerOptions
from teams.state import TurnState
from botbuilder.core.teams import TeamsInfo
import aiohttp

from config import Config
import pandas as pd

from botbuilder.schema import Activity, ActivityTypes

config = Config()

# Create AI components
model: OpenAIModel

model = OpenAIModel(
    AzureOpenAIModelOptions(
        api_key=config.AZURE_OPENAI_API_KEY,
        default_model=config.AZURE_OPENAI_MODEL_DEPLOYMENT_NAME,
        endpoint=config.AZURE_OPENAI_ENDPOINT,
    )
)
    
prompts = PromptManager(PromptManagerOptions(prompts_folder=f"{os.getcwd()}/prompts"))

planner = ActionPlanner(
    ActionPlannerOptions(model=model, prompts=prompts, default_prompt="chat")
)

# Define storage and application
storage = MemoryStorage()
bot_app = Application[TurnState](
    ApplicationOptions(
        bot_app_id=config.APP_ID,
        storage=storage,
        adapter=TeamsAdapter(config),
        ai=AIOptions(planner=planner),
    )
)   

@bot_app.conversation_update("membersAdded")
async def on_members_added(context: TurnContext, state: TurnState):
    print("***************in on_members_added**************************")
    print(f"Activity type: {context.activity.type}")
    try:
        await context.send_activity(f"Hello!  How can I assist you today? ") 
    except Exception as e:
        await context.send_activity("Hello! How can I assist you today? There is some error here")
        print(f"Error fetching user info: {e}")


@bot_app.error
async def on_error(context: TurnContext, error: Exception):
    # This check writes out errors to console log .vs. app insights.
    # NOTE: In production environment, you should consider logging this to Azure
    #       application insights.
    print(f"\n [on_turn_error] unhandled error: {error}", file=sys.stderr)
    traceback.print_exc()

    # Send a message to the user
    await context.send_activity("The bot encountered an error or bug.")

I tried adding following function to bot.py but it didn't work. Its checking the input text correctly and then responds back to user on emulator but it doesn't go back to normal process of listening and waiting for next input. Also, it doesn't call Azure Open AI service in else part.
# Sample test for bot_app.on_turn
@bot_app.before_turn
async def test_on_turn(context: TurnContext, state: TurnState):
    print("in test_on_turn", context.activity.type)
    if context.activity.type == ActivityTypes.message:
        user_message = context.activity.text.strip().lower()
        # Simulate different responses based on the user's message
        if "hey" in user_message:
            await context.send_activity(f"Hey receiveddd   {context.activity.type}")
        else:
            # how to call the handler for normal process?
    else:
        # Handle other types of activities
        await context.send_activity(f"Hello!  How can I assist you today?) 


Check for specific input, send a response if the input matches, and then return to stop further processing. If no match is found, let the bot continue with its normal flow (calling Azure OpenAI)

first three steps I am able to do but how to continue the normal flow?
there are two separate files one is app.py and other bot.py. where should I be implementing above change?

I have included suggested changes in test_on_turn(context: TurnContext, state: TurnState), if is working fine but in else how to resume normal flow. because the bot process is actually executing from app.py

To achieve the desired behavior—skipping Azure OpenAI processing for specific messages while allowing others to continue—the test_on_turn method in bot.py will need to integrate with the normal message-handling flow of bot_app.

In bot.py, you’ve already implemented the conditional logic in test_on_turn. For messages that should bypass Azure OpenAI, you send a response and return early. For all other messages, you want to resume the normal flow, which is done by invoking the default message handling pipeline.

Updated test_on_turn method in bot.py:
@bot_app.before_turn
async def test_on_turn(context: TurnContext, state: TurnState):
    print("in test_on_turn", context.activity.type)
    if context.activity.type == ActivityTypes.message:
        user_message = context.activity.text.strip().lower()

        # Bypass Azure OpenAI processing for specific messages
        if "hey" in user_message:
            await context.send_activity(f"Hey! How can I help you?")
            return  # Early return to stop further processing

    # Continue with normal flow (i.e., Azure OpenAI processing)
    # Let the bot application handle the request as it normally would
    await bot_app.default_turn(context, state)


The bot replies with, "Hey! How can I help you?" and does not call Azure OpenAI.

Log when handling both bypass and normal flows:
2024-10-15 14:32:12 [INFO] Starting bot...
2024-10-15 14:32:15 [DEBUG] on_messages *************
2024-10-15 14:32:15 [DEBUG] in test_on_turn message
2024-10-15 14:32:15 [DEBUG] User input detected: hey
2024-10-15 14:32:15 [INFO] Sending custom response: Hey! How can I help you?
2024-10-15 14:32:15 [DEBUG] Early return: Skipping Azure OpenAI

2024-10-15 14:32:20 [DEBUG] on_messages *************
2024-10-15 14:32:20 [DEBUG] in test_on_turn message
2024-10-15 14:32:20 [DEBUG] User input detected: tell me about quantum physics
2024-10-15 14:32:20 [DEBUG] Message doesn't match bypass conditions. Resuming normal flow.
2024-10-15 14:32:20 [INFO] Passing message to Azure OpenAI for processing
2024-10-15 14:32:25 [DEBUG] Azure OpenAI response received: Quantum physics is the study of matter and energy...
2024-10-15 14:32:25 [INFO] Sending response back to user: Quantum physics is the study of matter and energy...

Updated:
Updated test_on_turn function (no recursion):
@bot_app.before_turn
async def test_on_turn(context: TurnContext, state: TurnState):
    print("in test_on_turn", context.activity.type)
    
    if context.activity.type == ActivityTypes.message:
        user_message = context.activity.text.strip().lower()

        # Bypass Azure OpenAI processing for specific messages
        if "hey" in user_message:
            print(f"User input detected: {user_message}")
            await context.send_activity(f"Hey! How can I help you?")
            print("Sending custom response: Hey! How can I help you?")
            return  # Early return to stop further processing
    
    # No return here: we let the normal flow (on_turn) continue if no match
    print(f"Message doesn't match bypass conditions. Continuing with Azure OpenAI processing.")


Thanks for the reply with the code. I dnt see default_turn implemented in teams->app.py. However, there is on_turn activity. if I use that it returns error "RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object".  Can you please share the default_turn method definition? For now it goes back to default on_messages() (which is in app.py) and over there it is calling await bot_app.process(req) and input argument to that is post request. Sorry for too many questions, I am new to this space :)

No worries at all! Instead of directly calling on_turn, we’ll ensure the message continues through the pipeline properly after custom logic. You don’t need to manually invoke on_turn. This method will be automatically called by the framework when you pass the message into bot_app.process() in app.py. In the before_turn, you can check for your conditions (like "hey") and return early. If not, the pipeline will continue to on_turn for further processing.
